# Issue with ldap_bind() with blank user name and password

Tags: php

First of all LDAP_bind anonymous is enabled. The problem that i am having is the following:

This code works fine without a problem:

```
<?php
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';   
$ldappass = 'password';  

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {
    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }
}
?>
```

This one below returns "success" no matter what

```
   <?php
    $ldaprdn  = '';   
    $ldappass = '';  

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    if ($ldapconn) {
        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "LDAP bind successful...";
        } else {
            echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Note that the credentials are left blank in this version. I do not like the fact that if the credentials are left blank that this thing goes and lets you in.  Am i doing something wrong? Or simply this ldap_bind() is convoluted. I would think that if i call the function with three parameters that it should not default to anonymous.

I can work around that by setting the username and password to dummy values in case the username and passwords are left blank but this is not good practice at all. 
Please Help...

source:http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing LDAP authentication for a web app? If so, this is what you need to do:

1. Using an privileged bind, fetch the user's DN (or UPN if using Active Directory) by using the provided username in a search filter.*
2. If that fails, then the username is incorrect, and let the user know that username/password is incorrect.
3. If it is successful, take the DN and bind again using that DN and the provided password.
4. Now, this should either succeed or fail properly.

In other words, don't just take the passed in username and try to bind using that.

* If you provide more details about what you are trying to do and what LDAP server you are using, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I am using MS "active directory". Question?

Comment: I am using MS "active directory". 

First: Using a privileged bind (does that mean that i have to hard code the username and password of that privileged account? If yes (i am trying to avoid that). 

Second, any reasons why i should not bind directly using the provided credentials?   FYI: i am just creating an authentication class to allow users to log into my applications using their network usernames and passwords. 

Thanks Lucas.

Comment: Is everyone in the same domain? If so, then you can skip the privileged bind part, and either force-qualify everyone's name, like "domain\<username the user passed in>" or use their UPN, which is something like "username@domain.suffix". You can search AD yourself (as you) to find out what everyone's UPN looks like. By doing this you will never be sending in a blank username, because, at the minimum, it will either have "domain\" or "@domain.suffix". Let me know if that does not make sense.